# unexpected CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist AND CryptographicException: Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption, installation

We're trying to do this for our C# (.net 3.5) application on our XP SP2 machines (Win7 later).

In our installer (created by VS2008), we're encrypting our connection string with `AES` key and iv, and then creating a `RSA key-pair` and storing them in `MachineKeyStore`. The installer will use the `RSA public key` to encrypt the `AES` key and iv, and store the encrpted key and iv with the encrypted connection string.

After installation, our application will read the encrypted connection string with the encrypted AES key and iv back, and use the `RSA private key` (from `MachineKeyStore`) to decrypt the `AES` key and iv and then decrypt the connection string with the `AES` key and iv.

The installer and our application share a `constant string` for the `container name` of the `MachineKeyStore`.

I know where the key-pair is stored, so I can monitor it to see if key-pair is deleted, updated or created.

I did some tests and found some interesting things (unexpected) but don't know why it is like that. My user account is Admin account.

1. The installer can delete the stored `key-pair` created by our application and create a new one immediately with the same container name;
2. The installer can update `key-pair` created by our application (not delete and create again, it is overwriting, I think - but this should not happen according to the doc)
3. Our application cannot delete the key-pair created by the installer: `CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist.` exception will happen when the key-pair actually exists there;
4. Our application cannot create a new one when the installer-created key-pair is there: `CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist.`
5. Our application cannot access the key-pair created by the installer, 
   `CryptographicException: Access is denied.` will happen in that case. The encryption in the installer works with `AES` and `RSA public key`. When the application tries to use the stored `private key` to do decryption, an "`Access is denied`" exception will occur.

Our code follows:

```
public static void CreateRSAKeyPair(string keyContainerName)
        {
            DeleteRSAKeyPair(keyContainerName);

            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = keyContainerName;
            cspParams.Flags |= CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;

            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
            {
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            }
        }



public static void DeleteRSAKeyPair(string keyContainerName)
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = keyContainerName;
            cspParams.Flags |= CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;

            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
            {
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                try
                {
                    rsa.Clear();
                }
                catch (CryptographicException ex)
                {
                    Log.logItem(LogType.Exception, "RSA key clear error, can be ignored", "SecurityMgr::DeleteRSAKeyPair()", "CryptographicException msg=" + ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Code to access `private key` for decryption:

```
private static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] inputData, string keyContainerName)
        {
            byte[] resultData = null;
            try
            {
                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
                cspParams.Flags |= CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
                cspParams.KeyContainerName = keyContainerName;
                using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
                {
                    //rsaProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
                    //private key
                    RSAParameters rsaParams = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(true);
                    rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
                    resultData = rsaProvider.Decrypt(inputData, false);
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex)
            {
                string msg = "CryptographicException: keyContainerName=" + keyContainerName + "\nmsg=" + ex.ToString();
                Log.logItem(LogType.Exception, "RSA decryption exception", "SecurityMgr::RSADecrypt()", msg);
            }
            return resultData;
        }
```

Can RSA asymmetric encryption be used like this?

**EDIT:**

Doing the same thing (with AES and RSA encryption) for the connection string within our application (without the installer involved) works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The actual question is not very clear. However, I see a few things in your code:

- You export the key pair (private and public) from the Provider into the parameters. People get confused about the boolean parameter. IT does not mean it exports ONLY the private key. If you set it to true (export private key) both your PUBLIC and PRIVATE keys will be exported.
- The same keys you exported from your RSA Provider instance, you are importing back into the same provider. That does not make any sense.
- Remove the ExportParameters and ImportParameters lines, they accomplish nothing. Your key(s) should already be into the RSA Provider if the container name you specified in the constructor is valid and exists.
- With asymmetric cryptography you use the PRIVATE key to encrypt because that you do not share. You then use the PUBLIC key to decrypt because the other party (receiver) should only hold your PUBLIC key to be able to decrypt. If they have your PRIVATE key the whole scheme is compromised.

Comment: For anyone still reading this, technically the process of **public** > **private** (encrypt with public, decrypt with private) is called *encryption*, and is used for encrypting for a single target who can decrypt it. The reverse process (**private** > **public**) is called *signing*, which verifies the identity of the source (as only they could have "encrypted" it), but the public key (i.e. anyone) can "decrypt" (verify) it. Just a semantic, but important, distinction in the security model.